# Can I use a value inside a component in another component in React hooks (function component)?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, components, react-props

component1.js

```
const component1= (props) => {
     const [**selectedCountry**, setSelectedCountry] = useState();
         <Dropdown onSelect={eventKey => {
          const { code } = countries.find(({ code }) => eventKey === code);
setSelectedCountry(eventKey);
setToggleContents(<><FlagIcon code={code} /> </>);
         }}
       >                            
<Dropdown.Menu>
 {countries.map(({ code, title }) => (
<Dropdown.Item key={code} eventKey={code}><FlagIcon code={code} /> {title}</Dropdown.Item>
   ))}
 </Dropdown.Menu>
</Dropdown>
    .
    .
    }
```

a variable within this component. It becomes setSelectedCountry according to the dropdown change. how can i get this value in component2.js (i need selectedCountry value) ?

```
export default function component2() {

       useEffect(() => {
        
    postService.getLanguage(**HERE VALUE**).then((response)=>{
            setData(response.data);
        },
        (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        }
        );
}, []);

   ***I will take this value as a parameter and evaluate it in get (selectedCountry)How can I ***
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can. Component 1 can pass `value` and/or `setValue` as props to Component 2 for example. There are other ways. What have you tried? Is there any ***specific*** issue? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I couldn't use the props correctly, I guess that's why I wrote it @DrewReese

Comment: Ok. Can you share a more tangible and representative code example of your *actual* code you've an issue working with? Otherwise you've essentially asked a Yes/No question that isn't very interesting or helpful to future readers.

Comment: I updated the question, you are right @DrewReese

Comment: Is component 1 rendering component 2? Are these sibling components? What is the relationship between these two components that you need to share the component 1 state value of?

Comment: no , actually 2 different component. component 1 is Header.js. component 2 is Navbar.js. language dropdown in header.js. but product menu in navbar.js . Product menu comes from api so , I'm sending it as a parameter in the navbar according to the value from headerjs (must be parameter= selectedCountry). @DrewReese

Comment: I see. Then you may want to consider [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to a common ancestor component and passing state and state updater function down as props to the components that care. If there a lot of separation between the components and the state, then bumping to using a React context and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use createContext and useContext function here: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Alternatively you can use Redux to help you manage states used by multiple components.